# Javascript property from variable

Tags: javascript, variables, object, properties

I have a problem with my JavaScript code. I'm starting with some more complex things right now, seemed to find some answers on the net, but unfortunately I can't get it fixed. The problem is:

I want the variables `sGetMobileField` and `ValMob` to get in the parameters, but like this it isn't working:

```
var oFieldValues = { sGetMobileField:) { Value: ValMob } };
```

Variables don't seem to work as a object property. Anybody can help me fix it?

Thanks,
Dane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var oFieldValues = { };
oFieldValues[ sGetMobileField ] = { Value: ValMob };
```

You can use variables as property identifiers, but not inside an object literal. You have to create the object first, and may then add dynamic properties using

```
obj[ varToHoldPropertyName ] = someValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the syntax doesn't look right. I guess the ")" after `sGetMobileField:` is a typo. However, what are you doing here is set a property called "sGetMobileField":

```
var oFieldValues = { sGetMobileField: { Value: ValMob } };
```

Exactly for the same reason that with `Value` are you set a property called "Value" and not a property that get its name from a `Value` variable. It is consistent, right? So you will have:

```
console.log(oFieldValues.sGetMobileFields.Value) // the content of ValMob.
```

Luckily in JS you can use the square bracked notation instead of the dot notation. It means, you can access to a property using a string. So, for instance:

```
console.log("Hello");
```

is the same of:

```
console["log"]("Hello");
```

Therefore, you can use the value of a variable to specify the property of the object to access. In your case:

```
var oFieldValues = {};

oFieldValues[sGetMobileField] = { Value: ValMob };
```

Notice that following the naming convention usually used in JS, `Value` should be `value` and `ValMob` should be `valMob`.